# How to seed the request body directly from the pre request script on postman

Tags: api, request, postman

I created JSON object (**movieData**) and saved it as a global variable (all my test cases).
I want to get part of the data (everytime single case) and send it to **request body** from the **pre-request** script.

```
const movieData = {
   env: "testing",
   domain: "",
   tests: {
     test1: { 

       body: {
         movie_id: 568,
         title: "wonder-woman",
         description: "bla bla bla",
       }
       .... 
     },
     test2: { 

       body: {
         movie_id: 232,
         title: "spider-man",
         description: "bla bla bla",
       }
       .... 
     },
     test3: { 

       body: {
         movie_id: 212,
         title: "just-woman",
         description: "bla bla bla",
       }
       .... 
     },
     test4: { 

       body: {
         movie_id: 534,
         title: "just-man",
         description: "bla bla bla",
       }
       .... 
     }

   }
}
```

**pre-request:**

`var movies = JSON.parse(pm.globals.get('movieData'));
const test = movies.tests.test1.body;
pm.globals.set('test', test);`

**body:**

`"{{test}}"`

Anyone help how to do that?

Comment: so i understand...you want set item in global and use it everywhere later...am i correct peter ??

Comment: aha ... I saw ..the *Pre-request Script* doesn't actually get the dynamic variable ... so gettting body by **console.log( pm.request.body);** in *Pre-request Script* is wrong .. this console should be done in the **Tests**..... so your body is actually working...may I know are you getting the response or some error is there

Answer (score 3):

it is easier then you think... a `" "` would to the dynamic adding trick

as per docs.. the dynamic variable are to be

this is my email body..

```
{
    "email": "{{email}}",   //notice the " " quotes
    "password": "cityslicka"
}
```

[image]

I am dynamically changing the {{email}} and {{target}} in the pre-request scripts ...

**Notice** : *{{target}}* is in URL **without** quotes where *"{{email}}"* is in the body and has 'em ***" "***

[image]

Comment: Hi Raja, thanks for your answer but that's not what I'm trying to get. I'm already getting the data from the global variable, but **I'm trying to set the body request from the pre-request  script window**

Comment: ok on reading again.....i think you intend to hit a url..and the body of whose comes from a list of predfined json... and this should go over an iteration...am i somewhat near now   ??

Comment: Yes but for now I'm just trying to solve it for a single test case, but when I'm **console.log(test)**, I'm getting the data however, I can't see it as part of my request body

Comment: ahah... i think i am know some sort of arrangment..let my show you...incase you would like it

Comment: ahaha there is it...i think you missed them "quotes"

Comment: That's what I did but I can't get it on the body

Comment: then may be  your **const test**  isn't returning the body.. do a console.log there..

Comment: I did **console.log(test)** and it has the body, but for some reason it does not show it on **"{{body]}"**

Comment: *{{test}}* is it a valid json ?? Show the json

Comment: Yes, the console.log(test) print a valid JSON

Answer (score 0):

**Pre-request script**

```
var jsonData = {
  "method": "test",
  "params": {
    "token": "hello"
  },
  "moreData": "2.0"
};


pm.globals.set("myreqbody", JSON.stringify(jsonData));
```

**Body**

```
{{myreqbody}}
```